# Why doesn't the human body lower sebum production in patients with chronic acne?

Tags: acne

#### Background

Nodular acne is a condition where sebum plugs usually cause bumps on, and inflammation of, the skin, before the sebum emerges or can be extracted with a comedo extractor. Occasioanlly, this happens without inflammation.

#### Treatment

Per a dermatologist I spoke with, topical retinoids open pores to help expel the trapped sebum, but only oral treinoin (E.g. accutane) can dwindle sebum production.

#### Question

Why does the body not decrease sebum production on its own?  Assuming the body's ability to detect the inflammation and acne nodes, why wouldn't it adjust sebum production?

Comment: Edited to remove personal info

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect; the body doesn't have that kind of feedback mechanism for sebaceous glands.  Feedback mechanisms exist in the body for many processes, but this is not one of them. [Excessive oil secretion](https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/seborrhoea/) is common, and it is not clear why some people have it and others do not. Sometimes acne results, but not always.

References:

- https://www.dermnetnz.org/topics/seborrhoea/